# Tectia command line - download files from server based on uploaded/modified date

Tags: command-line, vbscript, download, sftp

My server machine has a Unix OS. I am able to download files from my Unix server to local(windows) machine using scpg3 command line of Tectia. Now, I want to copy only those files which are uploaded (modified-date) on specific Date.

I used below command of scpg3 in my VBScript to download files from server folder. It is working to copy all the files, but now I want to copy files for specific date.

```
Set oFTPScriptFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

ioFTPScriptShell.Run "%comspec% /c scpg3 " & sUsername & "@" & remoteServer & ":" & sRemotePath & " " & strDirectory, 1, TRUE
```

Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think the `scpg3` can do this.

If you use the `scpg3` for the SFTP protocol, you can use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) instead:

```
ioFTPScriptShell.Run "%comspec% /c winscp.com /command ""option batch abort""" _
  & " ""option confirm off""" _
  & " ""open sftp://" & sUsername & "@" & remoteServer & """" _
  & " ""get -filemask=*>=2013-04-23<2013-04-24 " & sRemotePath _
  & " " & strDirectory & """", 1, TRUE
```

Note the `-filemask=*>=2013-04-23<2013-04-24` switch of the `get` command.

For details see:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time

Alternatively, you can consider using WinSCP .NET/COM library directly from your VBScript:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_com_wsh

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*